# Use jQuery to add a class to clicked element and append content to a div

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here's a page where I'm working out how to make an interactive/choose-your-own-adventure story: http://victoriabrockmeier.com/querent/codetest.html

When a user clicks the word "stairs," I want to add the class "disabled" to that element, then add the next piece of the story.  Here's the code that I think is relevant, pulled out of the page:

```
<div id="ongoingStory"><p>This wasn&rsquo;t where you meant to go.</p>
   <p>You were walking, and thinking, and now that you&rsquo;ve come back to the present, you&rsquo;re looking at brick on two sides and a slatted, padlocked gate between them.  You&rsquo;ve come up an alley.  Or down one.</p>
   <p>Up a set of <a href="#" id="stairs">stairs</a> bolted precariously to one building&rsquo;s brick side, there&rsquo;s a door.  Above it, a sign juts out: <span class="smcaps">Sparrow Aisling / Psychic</span>.  Barely readable in the dusk, but there it is.</p></div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="narrative.js"></script>
```

and from narrative.js --

```
var climbStairs = "<p>You climb the stairs and go through the door.</p><p>Inside, there&rsquo;s a red velvet sofa, diamond-tufted, and an ottoman to one side.  Heavy green curtains and a spray of tiny, ornately framed <a href=\"#\">mirrors</a> occupy the back wall.  Occult clutter fills the rest of the room &mdash; candles in cups, crystals, brass bells and bowls, figurines from a number of different religions, a little round tea set, and bundles of dried herbs and sticks.</p><p>The obligatory cat, gray, looks up at you, twitches its tail, and goes back to staring out the room&rsquo;s one window.</p><ul><li><a href=\"#\">> Sit and wait.</a></li><li><a href=\"#\">> Nose around while you wait.</a></li></ul>"

$( document ).ready( function() {
   $( "#stairs" ).click( function() {
      $( this ).addClass( "disabled");
      $( "#ongoingStory" ).append( climbStairs );
   });

});
```

The last time I tried to script anything more interactive than a menu bar was more than a decade ago, so be gentle.  I'm sure I'm completely wrong about the syntax, or the order things need to be in, or I didn't escape something that needs to be escaped, or something really basic like that.

Comment: You forgot a closing quote in your `narrative.js` at line 4, hence your script stops there. You should always check the browser console first if something is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted is valid, however on your page the following line:

```
var sit = "<p>You settle on the velvet sofa, and the cat jumps down next to you. Assuming you&rsquo;re not allergic to cats, you pet it, and it purrs.  If you&rsquo;re allergic, presumably you begin itching or sneezing, or both.</p><p>You&rsquo;re now Patient.</p><p>After some time, a woman, bony and on the tall side, emerges from between the curtains.</p>
```

Is missing a closing `"` at the end.